# Is it possible to specify a different zshrc file on login over ssh?

Tags: server, bash, ssh, login, zsh

I spend all day ssh'ing into servers for work and the remote user is one that is shared by myself and several colleagues so I can't just blindly customise the shell as not everyone will want my tweaks and changes.

Is their a way to specify an alternate .zshrc file for use upon login, for example:

```
ssh user@someserver zsh --rcfile .zshrc.mine
```

I have reviewed the man pages and googled and so far have not come up with a solution.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: See this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131716/start-zsh-with-a-custom-zshrc

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for pointing me over their that works a treat :-)

Comment: If you are using an account that is "shared by myself and several colleagues", it is a **BAD PRACTICE**. Who do you blame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change where `zsh` looks for its user configuratation files (`.zshenv`, `.zprofile`, `.zshrc`, `.zlogin`), you have to set the `ZDOTDIR` environment variable to the path where they reside. `ZDOTDIR` may contain an absolute or relative path, where relative paths are relative to the current working directory when starting `zsh`. If `ZDOTDIR` is not set, `zsh` looks in `$HOME`.

So, if you put your personal `.zshrc` into the directory `$HOME/.my_zsh`, you should be able to use it on the remote server by connecting with the following command:

```
ssh -t user@someserver ZDOTDIR=.my_zsh zsh
```

The parameter `-t` forces pseudo-tty allocation, which `ssh` usually does only if no command is passed (i.e. if a remote shell is opened). In this case the command `ZDOTDIR=.my_zsh zsh` is passed, which sets `ZDOTDIR` (scoped only to the current command) and runs `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Your .ssh session has 3 environment variables defined:

```
  SSH_CLIENT=127.0.0.1 42421 22  
  SSH_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1 42421 127.0.0.1 22  
  SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
```

Your values after the "=" may differ.

You could have your `.zshrc` file check for them, and do somerthing different.